# -ObjC linker flag - When trying to add it to "Other Linker Flags" I get an error

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa, google-analytics

I'm trying to add the facebook SDK 3.2 to my app but after I add the -ObjC linker flag (as described in their video) I get a lot of duplicates warnings and I can't run the app with the error:

```
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_GAI.defaultTracker_ in:
    /Users/gool/proj/Frameworks/GANT/libGoogleAnalytics.a(GAI.o)
    /Users/gool/proj/Frameworks/GANT/libGoogleAnalytics_debug.a(GAI.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_GAI.dispatcher_ in:
    /Users/gool/proj/Frameworks/GANT/libGoogleAnalytics.a(GAI.o)
    /Users/gool/proj/Frameworks/GANT/libGoogleAnalytics_debug.a(GAI.o)
duplicate symbol _kGAIProduct in:
    /Users/gool/proj/Frameworks/GANT/libGoogleAnalytics.a(GAI.o)
    /Users/gool/proj/Frameworks/GANT/libGoogleAnalytics_debug.a(GAI.o)
duplicate symbol _kGAIVersion in:
    /Users/gool/proj/Frameworks/GANT/libGoogleAnalytics.a(GAI.o)
    /Users/gool/proj/Frameworks/GANT/libGoogleAnalytics_debug.a(GAI.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_GAI.trackUncaughtExceptions_ in:
    /Users/gool/proj/Frameworks/GANT/libGoogleAnalytics.a(GAI.o)
    /Users/gool/proj/Frameworks/GANT/libGoogleAnalytics_debug.a(GAI.o)

        /Users/gool/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(Facebook.o)
    ld: 172 duplicate symbols for architecture i386
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you clicked the checkmark ( add to targets ) while adding the sdk to your app?

Comment: Yes, Did it twice and made sure the add to targets is checked. I followed this:  "Choose 'Create groups for any added folders' and deselect 'Copy items into destination group's folder (if needed)' to keep the reference to the SDK installation folder, rather than creating a copy."

Comment: ok in the other linker flags add this command -ObjC -all_load It may help you

Comment: after every change don't forget to clean the project

Comment: Most likely the problem can be solved by looking at the "lot of duplicates warnings".

Comment: Couldn't find the problem there, I edited my question with part of the warnings I get. Tried cleaning Derived Data but it didn't do much.

Comment: Did you see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12352267/duplicate-symbol-objc-class-facebook ?

Comment: it may help you dude Another reason this error often happens is accidentally importing the .m file instead of the .h file .

Comment: @MatthiasBauch Just now. I do have an old FBConnect class in my project but I couldn't understand the answer from the link you gave on how to fix it.

Comment: A small update. The problem is there if I add the -ObjC even before adding the facebook SDK so it must be something with google Analytics and the warnings above (which I don't get before adding the -ObjC)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Deleting libGoogleAnalytics_debug.a and the facebook old sdk solved my problem